# Printing on same line in Python

Tags: python

Given 4 floating-point numbers. Use a string formatting expression with conversion specifiers to output their product and their average as integers (rounded), then as floating-point numbers.

Output each rounded integer using the following:

```
print('{:.0f}'.format(your_value))
```

Output each floating-point value with three digits after the decimal point, which can be achieved as follows:

```
print('{:.3f}'.format(your_value))
```

Ex: If the input is:

```
8.3
10.4
5.0
4.8
```

This returns:

```
2072

7

2071.680

7.125
```

Should be:

```
2072 7
2071.680 7.125
```

My code:

```
    num1 = float(input())
    num2 = float(input())
    num3 = float(input())
    num4 = float(input())
    avg = (num1 + num2 + num3 + num4) / 4.0
    product = (num1 * num2 * num3 * num4)

    print('{:.0f}'.format(product, end = ' ')), print('{:.0f}'.format(avg))
    print('{:.3f}'.format(product, end = ' ')), print('{:.3f}'.format(avg))
```

Comment: The `, end = ' '` should not be in the `.format()` function

Comment: There are a few ways to get the result you want, you can research about `fstring` or other methods other than `end=' '`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues with this...

First of all, you aren't actually passing the end value to the print statement, the syntax is as follows.

```
print(item.format(), end="")
```

Secondly, it's not very clear why you're adding 2 prints per line. Youre also calling a print function inside of another print, if we simplify your code to just contain `x` where you're passing something to print, it would look like this:

```
print(x, print(x))
```

You can just as easily add them all to one print statement as follows:

```
print('{:.0f}'.format(product, end = ' '), '{:.0f}'.format(avg), '{:.3f}'.format(product),'{:.3f}'.format(avg))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using those long print statements just use this:

```
print(f"{product:.0f}", f"{avg:.0f}", f"{product:.3f}", f"{avg:.3f}")
```

Output -

```
2072 7 2071.680 7.125
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to print it this way essentially using .format and {} :

```
   num1 = float(input())
    num2 = float(input())
    num3 = float(input())
    num4 = float(input())
    avg = (num1 + num2 + num3 + num4) / 4.0
    product = (num1 * num2 * num3 * num4)
    
    print('{:.0f} {:.0f} {:.3f} {:.3f}'.format(product, avg, product, average))
```